# run script as root bash

Tags: bash, unix

I have the below bash script that I'm trying to schedule as a cron job.
I have it in /etc/cron.d/cronjob

```
*/1 * * * * root /home/area/reboot.sh
```

But it's not working...
if I run the script from the command line using

```
sudo /home/area/reboot.sh
```

if works fine

below is the script

```
#!/bin/bash

    if [[ `awk '{print $0/60;}' /proc/uptime | cut -d . -f1` -gt 10 ]];then
    echo 1 > /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq
    echo b > /proc/sysrq-trigger
    fi
```

Comment: Remove that `root` from the `*/1 * * * * root /home/area/reboot.sh` line . Why is it even there? `cron` runs as root, so all script will be run as root. Also why do you want to run each second a script on your machine, that checks if the time is dividable by 60 and then greater then 10. This makes no sense.

Comment: that was just there for testing - it would run once an hour or something.  Any crontable file in /etc/cron.d/ needs the root entry

Answer (score 0):

Just use `sudo crontab -e` to edit the crontab

Also use

```
*/1 * * * * /home/area/reboot.sh
```

instead of

```
*/1 * * * * root /home/area/reboot.sh
```

Comment: the crontab file is  in /etc/cron.d I don't want to use root's crontab if possible

Comment: It's not possible only root's crontab can execute root action

Answer (score 0):

Set path at the beginning of your script:

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

Answer (score 0):

At this task there are some misleading infos.

First, for the system cron tables (/etc/crontab, /etc/cron.d/*) a username is needed. The job is executed under the environment or that user. This is a difference to the usual user-crontab. So This is correct:

```
*/1 * * * * root /home/area/reboot.sh
            ^^^^
           username
```

About `*/1`: It means: Every minute, that can be divided by 1 without remainder. So it is the same as `*`.

An answer to your question:
I have no idea, what is going wrong. Setup of `PATH=` or `SHELL=` may be a solution, or not. Anyway, setup `MAILTO=` and cron will send you a mail on errors. Read `man 5 crontab`. If it is not available at your system, google it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have execute permission for the cron file.

> chmod +x /home/area/reboot.sh

Also try adding the sh in front of the script. So in crontab -e

> */1 * * * * /bin/sh /home/area/reboot.sh

Answer (score 0):

fixed this with the below

```
echo 1 | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq
echo b | sudo tee /proc/sysrq-trigger
```